# How to make counter which always will have right number when iI refresh a page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can I make counter which always will have right number?
I realize that when i refresh page "count" is 0 but I don't know how to fix it.

HTML

```
<button class="push">Push</button>
<h1 class="out"></h1>
```

JS

```
let push = document.querySelector('.push');
let out = document.querySelector('.out');
let count = 0

push.onclick = function(){   
    localStorage.setItem("num",count);
    count++;
    let test = localStorage.getItem("num");
    out.innerHTML = test;
}

let test = localStorage.getItem("num");
out.innerHTML = test;
```

Comment: What is the "right number"?

Comment: `let count = 0` - you need to see if there is a number in localstorage and use that if it exists

Comment: moving `count++` above the line above it will fix *the right number*

Answer (score 0):

just to answer put that onclick in button tag like

`<button onclick='onclick()'>Push</button>
<div class='out'></div>`

In JS file:

```
let out = document.querySelector('.out');
let count = 0

function onclick(){   
  localStorage.setItem("num",count++);
  displayNumValue();
}
function displayNumValue() {
  let test = localStorage.getItem("num");
  out.innerHTML = test;
}
//this is for first time JS load
displayNumValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `count` only if there is no value exist in local storage.

```
var count = localStorage.getItem("num") != null ? localStorage.getItem("num") : 0;
```

You are saving the value of count before increment.

```
push.onclick = function(){  
    count++; 
    localStorage.setItem("num",count);
    let test = localStorage.getItem("num");
    out.innerHTML = test;
}
```